# How to rewrite a string and get params by pattern in php

Tags: php, string, url-rewriting, parameters

```
$string = '/start info@example.com';
$pattern = '/{command} {name}@{domain}';
```

get array params in php, Like the example below:

```
['command' => 'start', 'name' => 'info', 'domain' => 'example.com']
```

and

```
$string = '/start info@example.com';
$pattern = '/{command} {email}'; 
['command' => 'start', 'email' => 'info@example.com']
```

and

```
$string = '/start info@example.com';
$pattern = '{command} {email}';
['command' => '/start', 'email' => 'info@example.com']
```

Comment: `'/^\/(?P<command>\w+)\s(?P<name>[^@]+)\@(?P<domain>.+?)$/'`, preg_match, for example https://regex101.com/r/jN8gP7/1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Although one may guess what you imply, I'd recommend to add an explicit question to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a single line string you can use `preg_match` and a regular expression such as this

```
  preg_match('/^\/(?P<command>\w+)\s(?P<name>[^@]+)\@(?P<domain>.+?)$/', '/start info@example.com', $match );
```

But depending on variation in the data you may have to adjust the regx a bit.  This outputs

- command   [1-6]   `start`
- name  [7-11]  `info`
- domain    [12-23] `example.com`

but it will also have the numeric index in the array.

https://regex101.com/r/jN8gP7/1

Just to break this down a bit, in English.

The leading `^` is start of line, then named capture ( `\w` (any a-z A-Z 0-9 _ ) ) then a space `\s` then named capture of (  anything but the @t sign `[^@]` ), then the @t sign `@`, then name captured of ( anything `.+?` to the end `$` )

This will capture anything in this format,

(abc123_ ) space (anything but @)@(anything)

Comment: how to convert $pattern to preg_match ??
$pattern may be changed !!

Comment: that's a great tool

Comment: it's ok, doesn't properly handle some things, like global match in preg_replace, and / forward slashes need more escaping, but overall it works.

Comment: regx is like a whole other language, the `?P<name>` is a named capture group, you can change the `name` part tow whatever you want.  The ` ( )` is technically the capture group, the \w is same as [a-zA-Z0-9_]+, so a-z (both upper lower ) 0-9 the _ and the + is as many times as possible

Comment: The [^ ] is not matching, and the .+ is anything, so in English( basically ), that looks for any a-Z0-9_ a [\s]pace not a @ at sign, an at sign, then anything,